# 'Symbol' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, symbols

I am new to typescript and i cant understand what i am doing wrong in here.
I read it from the official documentation of typescript. The link is below.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html
The typescript version i have installed is 3.5.2

`let sym1 = Symbol();`

Comment: You're saying that transpiling error appears with this line? That's weird, there's nothing wrong with it and it transpiles for sure.

Comment: Yes It giving me the error when the code is correct.

Comment: Could you show us your tsconfig.json file?

Comment: The only code you've posted [works fine](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/DYUwLgBAzgngtgRggXggZXgIwPbABQCUA3AFBA), so you will need to give more information.  Please consider trying to provide a [mcve] so that we can see the same issue as you.  If you can't reproduce the problem in a standalone or other web IDE environment (stackblitz, codesandbox, etc) then the difference in configuration is likely your problem and you should be able to debug that difference.  My guess is that your `--lib` does not include ES2015 libraries.

Comment: jcalz your guess is absolutely correct. I need to update my lib to es6 from es5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Symbols is a feature that was introduced in ecmascript6. It's not working in es5 so i changed the target from "target": "es5" to "target": "es6" to make it work in tsconfig.json file